# "has" or "does" in an answer

Tags: grammar

There's a question in American English:

> Who has an extra ticket?

How to answer more correctly:

> That guy **has**.

or

> That guy **does**.

Comment: That guy has an extra ticket.

Comment: I mean a short answer, Ashish.

Comment: "has" or "does", of course